# no launcher activity was found even if i had declared one in the manifest

Tags: android

i declared the report file as my launcher. so its supposed to launch first when the app is started first. or do i get something wrong.
i get the error. no launch activity was found. thx guys

```
    <activity android:name=".report"   android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REPORT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>


    <activity android:name=".Main"   android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>

        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the action:name from .REPORT to .MAIN.  The action name corresponds to the intent action and not to the Activity name.

Fixed version of the above:

```
<activity android:name=".report" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>  
</activity>

<activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Comment: thx for the answer. if i do this its launching the application perfect after installing. but if i want to start the application from the icon it says: could not launch the requested activity.

Comment: can you clarify that?  What do you mean the application launches perfectly but not from the icon?  From where does it launch perfectly?  What's the problem?

Comment: im sorry. there was another mistake in the project. it has been the solution already. thanks for the answers!!!